# Update in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have below data in my table:

```
eff_dt      end_dt      type_cd status
1-Jan-14    5-Jan-14    AAA     0
5-Jan-14    7-Jan-14    null    1
7-Jan-14    10-Jan-14   null    1
10-Jan-14   15-Jan-14   BBB     0
15-Jan-14   21-Jan-14   null    1
21-Jan-14   25-Jan-14   null    1
25-Jan-14   30-Jan-14   CCC     0
```

I want to update data using self join .

After update table should look like:

```
eff_dt      end_dt  type_cd status
1-Jan-14    5-Jan-14    AAA 0
5-Jan-14    7-Jan-14    AAA 1
7-Jan-14    10-Jan-14   AAA 1
10-Jan-14   15-Jan-14   BBB 0
15-Jan-14   21-Jan-14   BBB 1
21-Jan-14   25-Jan-14   BBB 1
25-Jan-14   30-Jan-14   CCC 0
```

Please help me with the update query in teradata ?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
eff_dt      end_dt      type_cd status
1-Jan-14    5-Jan-14    AAA     0
5-Jan-14    7-Jan-14    null    1
7-Jan-14    10-Jan-14   null    1
10-Jan-14   15-Jan-14   BBB     0
15-Jan-14   21-Jan-14   null    1
21-Jan-14   25-Jan-14   null    1
25-Jan-14   30-Jan-14   CCC     0
```

given the above data, we can self join using status and dates.
end_dt of first row is basically the eff_dt of the 2nd row.

```
UPDATE A
FROM DB.TABLEA AS A, DB.TABLEA AS B
SET type_cd = B.type_cd
WHERE A.eff_dt = B.end_dt
and A.status = 1;
```

Do the same update again for to update the 3rd row status.
If the no. of rows is variable, then you will have to modify the query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT 
    t1.eff_dt, t1.end_dt, t2.type_cd, t1.status
FROM 
    yourtable t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE status = 0) t2 ON t1.end_dt >= t2.end_dt
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.end_dt ORDER BY t2.end_dt DESC) = 1
```

This is joining your table to a version of your table where only `status=0` records are present, since those are the ones with your non-null `type_cd`. It joins on date looking for any record that has a `type_cd` and the `end_dt` is less than the current records `end_dt`.

The `QUALIFY` windowing function at the end looks for records that have a `type_cd`  with the highest `end_dt`. The downside here is the larger your table gets the more records you generate in the join, so your intermediate result will grow substantially. Your results will be correct, but you'll be using up more and more spool space.

If you find the windowing function difficult to understand in this query, try running the query without it and `SELECT *`. You can work through the `QUALIFY` logic a little easier then.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table sample_1
(
eff_dt date,
end_dt date,
type_cd varchar(4)
,status int
);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-01',date '2014-01-05','aaa',0);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-05',date '2014-01-07',null,1);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-07',date '2014-01-10',null,1);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-10',date '2014-01-15','bbb',0);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-15',date '2014-01-21',null,1);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-21',date '2014-01-25',null,1);
insert into sample_1(date '2014-01-25',date '2014-01-30','ccc',0);

upd  tgt
from sample_1 tgt
, (
sel tgt.eff_dt,tgt.end_dt,lkp.type_cd,tgt.status
from sample_1 tgt,
(
sel tgt.*,max(eff_dt) over (order by eff_dt asc rows between 1 following and 1 following ) eff_dt1
from sample_1 tgt
where status=0 --type_cd is not null
) lkp
where tgt.eff_dt between lkp.eff_dt and coalesce  (eff_dt1,date '9999-12-31')
and coalesce ( tgt.type_cd,lkp.type_cd) =lkp.type_cd
) lkp
set type_cd=lkp.type_cd
where tgt.eff_dt=lkp.eff_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Filling those NULLs is a simple task for `LAST_VALUE`:

```
UPDATE tgt
FROM mytable tgt
,(
   SEL eff_dt,
      Last_Value(type_cd IGNORE NULLS) 
      Over (ORDER BY eff_dt) AS last_cd
   FROM mytable
   QUALIFY type_cd IS NULL
 ) AS src   
SET type_cd = src.last_cd
WHERE tgt.eff_dt= src.eff_dt
```

Assuming this was just an example and you must do this for a group of rows you better use MERGE, will never be slower, but might be faster:

```
MERGE INTO mytable AS tgt
USING
 (
   SEL eff_dt,
      Last_Value(type_cd IGNORE NULLS) 
      Over (ORDER BY eff_dt) AS last_cd
   FROM mytable
   QUALIFY type_cd IS NULL
 ) AS src   
-- ON must include at least all (P)PI columns of the target table
ON tgt.eff_dt = src.eff_dt
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET type_cd = src.last_cd
```